# Find $P(Y_1<Y_3)$?

Tags: probability, order-statistics

I am trying to answer this question

Let $Y_1,Y_2,Y_3$ be random variables with pdf $f(x)=2x$ for $0<x<1$. Find $P(Y_1<Y_3)$?

My solution:

Since

$P(Y_1<Y_3)+P(Y_3<Y_1)+P(Y_1=Y_3)=1$

and

$P(Y_3=Y_1)=0$

$P(Y_1<Y_3)=P(Y_3<Y_1)$

then

$P(Y_1<Y_3)=1/2$

Is this correct?

**Note:** This question was not in English originally. If translated exactly it says "$Y1,Y2,Y3$ are ordered/arranged values ​​for a random sample of size 3". Does this change the question?

Comment: You are correct, assuming they are iid.

Comment: @YJT, what is iid?

Comment: independent & identically distributed

Comment: @Stockfish, This question was not in English originally. If translated exactly it says "$Y1,Y2,Y3$ are ordered/arranged values ​​for a random sample of size 3". Does this change the question?

Comment: Yes,, @gbd .  That means they are *not* independent. However, if they are *ordered* then $Y_1<Y_3$ almost surely - so are you sure about that translation?

Comment: Maybe upload the original question? I guess someone here will be able to translate it correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Yes indeed, your reasoning is elegant and correct -- for independent random variables.

To confirm, by integration: $$\begin{align}\mathsf P(Y_1<Y_3)&=\int_0^1 \int_0^{y_3} 4y_1y_3~\mathrm d y_1~\mathrm dy_3\\[1ex]&=\int_0^1  2y_3^3~\mathrm dy_3 \\[1ex]&=\tfrac 12\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

> If translated exactly it says "Y1,Y2,Y3 are ordered/arranged values ​​for a random sample of size 3". Does this change the question?

... a little bit :(. They are [Order Statistics](http://www.math.ntu.edu.tw/%7Ehchen/teaching/LargeSample/notes/noteorder.pdf), and must be indicated with $Y_{(i)}$

As already noted in a previous comment, $\mathbb{P}[Y_{(1)}<Y_{(3)}]=1$ as $Y_{(1)}<Y_{(3)}$ a.s.

To confirm the result by integration, let's find the joint density

$f_{Y_{(1)}Y_{(3)}}(u,v)=24uv(v^2-u^2)$

$u,v \in [0;1]$

and then proceed by integration

$$\mathbb{P}[Y_{(1)}<Y_{(3)}]=\int_0^1 \int_0^v [24uv^3-24u^3v]dudv =...=1$$